# Powershell script to get NIC speed from remote hosts

Tags: powershell, network-programming

I'm trying to create PowerShell script to get the NIC speed of remote hosts, and output the end result to a txt file.

So far, this is what I've got:

```
Hostname
Get-NetAdapter | SELECT LinkSpeed
Out-File C:\CheckNIC-Speed\checknic.txt
```

That's a script for the local computer, but it also won't output the results to the txt, instead it will just create an empty file.

Now, I also need to run it on multiple remote hosts and get the output to the same file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
("Server1","Server2","Server3") | Foreach {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            LinkSpeed = (Get-NetAdapter).LinkSpeed -join " & "
            HostName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
        }
    }
} | Out-File "C:\File.txt"
```

This should retrieve info for any of the servers listed within the brackets, you can also import from a list.

look up [Invoke-Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) Help if you need to do this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmi-object for the same:

```
get-wmiobject win32_networkadapter -ComputerName Server01,Server02,Server03 | select name,speed, pscomputername
```

Comment: I tried that, But the result is not good..
I get all the hidden devices as well, and the speed is not the actual speed:
WAN Miniport (IP)
Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2  9223372036854775807
RAS Async Adapter
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2             100000
Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3  9223372036854775807
Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface       100000
Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #4  9223372036854775807
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3             100000
Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4             100000